# ipython not producing output graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython, pythonxy

SO I have recently started trying to use ipython, I am finding I cannot get it to produce an output graph. I am running the following code in ipython:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

regr.fit(x, y)
pl.plot(x, y, 'o')
pl.plot(x_test, regr.predict(x_test))
```

and I am recieving the output:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x21d453b0>]
```

With no image attatched.

I installed ipython using the pythonxy package.
Any thoughts of suggestions on methods to get plots outputting correctly in ipython

***See attached image:***
[image]

Comment: are you using ipython with the -pylab option ?

Comment: @joaquin yes I think so, see comment to answer provided by elyase

Comment: Which version of IPython are you on? Technically, I realize you tried using `--pylab=inline`. Can you just try running %matplotlib in a cell and then re-execute that code?

Comment: I am running `ipython-1.1.0-py2.7.egg-info` I tried to use Using  `%matplotlib` and i recieved `matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running in a cell:

```
%pylab inline    # or
%matplotlib inline
```

After that the plots should be displayed inline. Alternatively start the notebook using the inline option in the command line:

```
ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

Comment: My IPython is already running as follows: `C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython.exe notebook --pylab=inline`

Comment: @AEA, hmm, your code runs ok in my notebook, can you try resetting your matplotlib settings `rm .matplotlib/matplotlibrc`? Look [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) if you are on windows for the location of your matplotlibrc.

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import Image

# your code here

Image(data=<your_image_data_here>, embed=True)
```

Comment: received the error: `ERROR:astropy:TypeError: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x225DADB0> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I'm not sure what format is output from `plot()` but it needs to be png or else pass the argument `format='jpg'`  to `Image()`

Comment: For reference this is the tutorial I was following. I made it 3 mins in before I hit issues. :( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uX4ZirOiWkw